# What is the best way to pass multiple string variables to a query string in python3

Tags: python-3.x, string-concatenation

I need to create a dynamic query based on two string parameters:

```
description = "This is the description"
comment = "This is the comment"
query = "insert into case(desc, comm) value(description, comment)"
```

Note: 
there might be **single quote** and **double quotes** in both *description* and *comment*.

How do I use formatted %s to generate the query string?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Green Cloak Guy (his/her answer has minors to be corrected), the right query is:

query = f"insert into case(description, comment) value(\'{description}\', \'{comment}\')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an f-string.

```
query = f"insert into case({description}, {comment}) value({description}, {comment})"
```

Don't use any type of string formatting to do actual database queries - that leads to you having a SQL Injection problem. Use a database library instead, that properly sanitizes the data.

But if all you need to do is parse some variables into a string, this is more flexible than the `%` formatting that other languages tend to use (and that's technically still available in python via `"some_string %s %s %s" % (str1, str2, str3)"`)

Comment: Thank you, in the value part, both should be single quoted,